# Dynamic jQuery AppendTo Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page that is adding a toolbar to an item. That page is using some static IDs to make this happen. The most important line of code looks like this:

```
$('#tb').appendTo('.item-toolbar');
```

The above works as expected for a single item. But now, I'm trying to make this so that it work with multiple items. In an attempt to do this, I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9d78akj/1/). The most important code looks like this:

```
function moveNugget() {
  var selected = $('#selector').val();
  var tb = $('#tb');

  var items = $('.item-container');

  // The following line is the one that is giving me problems.
  //.appendTo('.item-toolbar');
}
```

If you visit the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9d78akj/1/), it will be more clear. Basically, a user can choose 1, 2, or 3 from a drop down. Once selected, the tool bar should be "appended to" the corresponding `item-toolbar`. My challenge is, I can't figure out how to create the selector to a dynamically selected item and use the `appendTo` function.

I really want to use the `appendTo` because my actual code is more complicated. I've tried to strip it down to the part that is giving me the issue. It's clearly my approach to using `appendTo`. Right now, I'm trying:

```
$(tb).appendTo('.item-toolbar');
```

However, this approach completely disregards the selected item. I'm not sure how to use the selected items toolbar within the context of `appendTo`.

Comment: Hi, if you find some answer helpful and it solve your problem check it as correct answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the variant of realization:

1. Add unique ids on each item-toolbar (For example view-0, view-1, view-2)

It will look like this:

```
<select id="selector">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="moveNugget();">
 Move
</button>
<br /><br />

<div class="view">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-title">
      [title]
    </div>
    <div id="view-0" class="item-toolbar">
      [tb]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="view">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-title">
      [title]
    </div>
    <div id="view-1" class="item-toolbar">
      [tb]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<hr />
<br />

<div class="view">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-title">
      [title]
    </div>
    <div id="view-2" class="item-toolbar">
      [tb]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />
<ul id="tb" style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>[1]</li>
  <li>[2]</li>
  <li>[3]</li>
</ul>
```

2. Then when you click on button you can append your toolbar to appropriate block

Here is changed function code:

```
function moveNugget() {
  var selected = $('#selector').val();
  var tb = $('#tb');

  var items = $('.item-container');

  // Add toolbar to appropriate block
  tb.appendTo('#view-' + selected);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvfgmw7y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function moveNugget() {
  var selected = $('#selector').val();
  var tb = $('#tb');
  var items = $('.item-container .item-toolbar')[selected];
  // The following line is the one that is giving me problems.
  tb.appendTo(items);
}
```